# Conflicting accordions.

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have two separate accordions that are are using similar jquery functions. One has nested accordions in it that need to expand and collapse when clicked, the other has just one accordion that needs to expand and collapse when clicked. The jquery code I have seems to conflicting with each other, is there a more efficient way to write this?

```js
    $('.accordion-title').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('.accordion-title').removeClass('active');
            $('.accordion-content').slideUp();
            $(this).addClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideDown();
        }
    });
```

```html
<section class="ac-container">
  <h2>Breakfast</h2>
  <dl class="accordion-title"><div><img src="img/breakfast/american.jpg" alt=""><span>American</span></div></dl>
  <div class="accordion-content"><p>Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows.</p></div>
  <dl class="accordion-title"><div><img src="img/breakfast/continental.jpg" alt=""><span>Continental</span></div></dl>
  <div class="accordion-content"><p>Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows.</p></div>
  <dl class="accordion-title"><div><img src="img/breakfast/english.jpg" alt=""><span>English</span></div></dl>
  <div class="accordion-content"><p>Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows.</p></div>
  <dl class="accordion-title"><div><img src="img/breakfast/health.jpg" alt=""><span>The Healthy Stuff</span></div></dl>
  <div class="accordion-content"><p>Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows.</p></div>
  <dl class="accordion-title"><div><img src="img/breakfast/misc.jpg" alt=""><span>Miscellaneous</span></div></dl>
  <div class="accordion-content"><p>Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows.</p></div>
</section>
```

```js
$(function () {
      $('.accordion-title').click(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideUp();
      } else {
      $(this).siblings('.accordion-title').removeClass('active');
      var $ct = $(this).siblings('.accordion-content').slideUp();
      $ct.find('.accordion-title.active').removeClass('active');
      $ct.find('.accordion-content').slideUp();
      $(this).addClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideDown();
      }
      });
});
```

```html
<form name="cform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="/regcamp.php" method="post" style="margin-top:5%;">
                 <dl class="accordion-title"><div><span>Camper 1 Information</span></div></dl>
                 <div class="accordion-content"><p>
                  <div class="formrow">
                   <div class="formitem col1of2">
                    <label class="label req" for="firstname">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Name" required="required" x-autocompletetype="given-name"/>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="formrow">
                   <div class="formitem">
                    <div class="label req">Gender</div>
                    <div class="ticks">
                     <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="gender1" value="Male" required="required"/>
                      <span>Male</span>
                     </label>
                     <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="gender1" value="Female" required="required"/>
                      <span>Female</span>
                     </label>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="formrow">
                   <div class="formitem col1of2">
                    <label class="label req" for="grade1">Grade in School</label>
                    <input type="text" name="grade1" id="grade1" placeholder="Grade in School" required="required" x-autocompletetype="given-name"/>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="formrow">
                   <div class="formitem col1of2">
                    <label class="label" for="bmoth1">Date of Birth</label>
                    <select name="bmonth1" id="bmoth1" x-autocompletetype="birth-month">
                     <option selected="selected">Month</option>
                     <option value="January">January</option>
                     <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
                     <option value="March">March</option>
                     <option value="April">April</option>
                     <option value="May">May</option>
                     <option value="June">June</option>
                     <option value="July">July</option>
                     <option value="August">August</option>
                     <option value="September">September</option>
                     <option value="October">October</option>
                     <option value="November">November</option>
                     <option value="December">December</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="bday1" id="bday1" x-autocompletetype="birth-day">
                     <option selected="selected">Day</option>
                     <option value="1">1</option>
                     <option value="2">2</option>
                     <option value="3">3</option>
                     <option value="4">4</option>
                     <option value="5">5</option>
                     <option value="6">6</option>
                     <option value="7">7</option>
                     <option value="8">8</option>
                     <option value="9">9</option>
                     <option value="10">10</option>
                     <option value="11">11</option>
                     <option value="12">12</option>
                     <option value="13">13</option>
                     <option value="14">14</option>
                     <option value="15">15</option>
                     <option value="16">16</option>
                     <option value="17">17</option>
                     <option value="18">18</option>
                     <option value="19">19</option>
                     <option value="20">20</option>
                     <option value="21">21</option>
                     <option value="22">22</option>
                     <option value="23">23</option>
                     <option value="24">24</option>
                     <option value="25">25</option>
                     <option value="26">26</option>
                     <option value="27">27</option>
                     <option value="28">28</option>
                     <option value="29">29</option>
                     <option value="30">30</option>
                     <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="year1" id="year1" x-autocompletetype="birth-year">
                     <option selected="selected">Year</option>
                     <option value="1995">1995</option>
                     <option value="1996">1996</option>
                     <option value="1997">1997</option>
                     <option value="1998">1998</option>
                     <option value="1999">1999</option>
                     <option value="2000">2000</option>
                     <option value="2001">2001</option>
                     <option value="2002">2002</option>
                     <option value="2003">2003</option>
                     <option value="2004">2004</option>
                     <option value="2005">2005</option>
                     <option value="2006">2006</option>
                     <option value="2007">2007</option>
                     <option value="2008">2008</option>
                     <option value="2009">2009</option>
                     <option value="2010">2010</option>
                     <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    </select>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="formrow">
                   <div class="formitem col1of2">
                    <label class="label" for="cshora">Enroll in Camp Shoreline</label>
                    <select id="cshora" name="cshora" x-autocompletetype="enroll">
                     <option selected="selected" value="No">Select</option>
                     <option value="Week">Camp Shoreline - $375</option>
                    </select>
                    <select  id="weekcsa" name="weekcsa" x-autocompletetype="week">
                     <option selected="selected">Select Date</option>
                     <option value="No">Select Date</option>
                     <option value="1 - June 8-12">June 8-12</option>
                     <option value="2 - June 15-19">June 15-19</option>
                     <option value="3 - June 22-26">June 22-26</option>
                     <option value="4 - June 29-July 3">June 29-July 3</option>
                     <option value="5 - July 6-10">July 6-10</option>
                     <option value="6 - July 13-17">July 13-17</option>
                     <option value="7 - July 20-24">July 20-24</option>
                     <option value="8 - July 27-31">July 27-31</option>
                     <option value="9 - August 3-7">August 3-7</option>
                     <option value="10 - August 10-14">August 10-14</option>
                     <option value="11 - August 17-21">August 17-21</option>
                    </select>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="formrow">
                   <div class="formitem col1of2">
                    <label class="label" for="level1a">Windsurfing &amp; Sailing Level I</label>
                    <select id="level1a" name="level1a" x-autocompletetype="level1a">
                     <option selected="selected" value="No">Select</option>
                     <option value="Week">WS/Sail Level I &nbsp;- $415</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="week1a" name="week1a" x-autocompletetype="week">
                     <option value="No">Select Date</option>
                     <option value="1 - June 8-12">June 8-12</option>
                     <option value="2 - June 15-19">June 15-19</option>
                     <option value="3 - June 22-26">June 22-26</option>
                     <option value="4 - June 29-July 3">June 29-July 3</option>
                     <option value="5 - July 6-10">July 6-10</option>
                     <option value="6 - July 13-17">July 13-17</option>
                     <option value="7 - July 20-24">July 20-24</option>
                     <option value="8 - July 27-31">July 27-31</option>
                     <option value="9 - August 3-7">August 3-7</option>
                     <option value="10 - August 10-14">August 10-14</option>
                     <option value="11 - August 17-21">August 17-21</option>
                    </select>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="formrow">
                   <div class="formitem col1of2">
                    <label class="label" for="level2a">Windsurfing &amp; Sailing Level II</label>
                    <select id="level2a" name="level2a" x-autocompletetype="level2a">
                     <option selected="selected" value="No">Select</option>
                     <option value="Week">WS/Sail Level II - $430</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="week2a" name="week2a" x-autocompletetype="week">
                     <option value="No">Select Date</option>
                     <option value="1 - June 8-12">June 8-12</option>
                     <option value="2 - June 15-19">June 15-19</option>
                     <option value="3 - June 22-26">June 22-26</option>
                     <option value="4 - June 29-July 3">June 29-July 3</option>
                     <option value="5 - July 6-10">July 6-10</option>
                     <option value="6 - July 13-17">July 13-17</option>
                     <option value="7 - July 20-24">July 20-24</option>
                     <option value="8 - July 27-31">July 27-31</option>
                     <option value="9 - August 3-7">August 3-7</option>
                     <option value="10 - August 10-14">August 10-14</option>
                     <option value="11 - August 17-21">August 17-21</option>
                    </select>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="formrow">
                   <div class="formitem col1of2">
                    <label class="label" for="options1">Options</label>
                    <select id="options1" name="options1" x-autocompletetype="options">
                     <option selected="selected" value="No">Select</option>
                     <option value="Weekly Extended Care">Weekly Extended Care - $150</option>
                     <option value="Weekly Lunch Pass">Weekly Lunch Pass - $40</option>
                     <option value="Week Lunch + Extended Care">Weekly Extended Care + Lunch Pass - $190</option>
                    </select>
                   </div>
                  </div>








                 </p>
                 <dl class="accordion-title"><div><span>Camper 2 Information</span></div></dl>
                 <div class="accordion-content"><p>
                  <div class="formrow">
                   <div class="formitem col1of2">
```

The second form is only partial code so it could fit in the post. Thanks.

Comment: Use a different id to identify element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to isolate the instance which you can do by traversing only within the immediate parent of each accordion title.

I'm not going to rewrite both sets but will give you the basic approach using the first

```
$('.accordion-title').click(function () {
        var $parent = $(this).parent();// returns <section class="ac-container">
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideUp();
        } else {
            // only look within instance of <section class="ac-container">
            $parent.find('.accordion-title').removeClass('active');
            $parent.find('.accordion-content').slideUp();
            $(this).addClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideDown();
        }
    });
```